# Slicing list with comparison operator without modules in python

Tags: python, indexing, slice, comparison-operators

I want to slice a list with comparison operator (<). I want to slice out the members of a list that is less than a particular number. For example

`x=[3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 14, 14, 15, 18, 21]`

I want to slice out member that are less than 13 only, that is `[3, 5, 7, 8, 12]`. I tried `x[x<13]` but it not working.

`[i<12 for i in x]` returns TRUE/FALSE list.

I will appreciate help in getting this done. Thanks

Comment: This is not a "slice" in standard python terminology, which implies something else, generally you would say "filter".

Comment: x = numpy.array([3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 14, 14, 15, 18, 21])             
    y = x[x[:] < 13]

Answer (score 1):

You were actually very close. This should work:

```
x=[3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 14, 14, 15, 18, 21]
[i for i in x if i < 12]
```

Output:

```
[3, 5, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Thank you. This work perfectly well